# Kafka Connect S3 - partitioner.class - TimeBasedPartitioner could not be found

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, apache-kafka-connect, partition

I am trying to run Kafka Connect S3 Sink docker, on the same host as the Kafka docker.
I want to partition the output basing on the wallclock time. However, my Kafka Connect failed to start up with the following error:

> ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kkconnect] Uncaught
>   exception in herder work thread, exiting:
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
>
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value
>   io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner for
>   configuration partitioner.class: Class
>   io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner could
>   not be found.

Here is the command I used to start that docker:

```
docker run -d \
  --name=my-kkc \
  --net=host \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --log-driver=awslogs \
  --log-opt awslogs-stream=kk-cn-1 \
  --log-opt awslogs-region=ap-southeast-2 \
  --log-opt awslogs-group=kafka-cn-1 \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=28082 \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="kkconnect" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="kkconnect-config" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="kkconnect-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="kkconnect-status" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_SCHEMA_COMPATIBILITY=NONE \
  -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java \
  -e CONNECT_NAME="s3-sink" \
  -e CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLASS="io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector" \
  -e CONNECT_TASKS_MAX=1 \
  -e CONNECT_TOPICS="mytopic" \
  -e CONNECT_ROTATE_INTERVAL_MS=60000 \
  -e CONNECT_FLUSH_SIZE=3 \
  -e CONNECT_S3_BUCKET_NAME="xxx-xxx" \
  -e CONNECT_S3_PART_SIZE=5242880 \
  -e CONNECT_STORAGE_CLASS="io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage" \
  -e CONNECT_FORMAT_CLASS="io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat" \
  -e CONNECT_FORMAT_BYTEARRAY_EXTENSION=json \
  -e CONNECT_PARTITIONER_CLASS="io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner" \
  -e CONNECT_PARTITION_DURATION_MS=60000 \
  -e CONNECT_PATH_FORMAT="'kafka/mytopic/year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH" \
  -e CONNECT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR=Wallclock \
  -e CONNECT_S3_COMPRESSION_TYPE=gzip \
  confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.0
```

Could you please help?

Thanks and regards,
Averell

Comment: Everything listed after `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` is not a valid env-var. Those need to be posted to the HTTP endpoint as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As @OneCricketeer mentioned in the comment, you need to specify all other parameters after `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` in a POST request.

So, after you've spun the container with all the variables above and including `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` then run the command:

```
curl -d @path/to/your-config.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:28082/connectors
```

Where `path/to/your-config.json` would look like this:

```
{
    "name": "s3-sink",
    "config": {
        "name": "s3-sink",
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "mytopic",
        // and so on...
    }
}
```